# Sum of values in a function called from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I have few text files containing some numbers in each line. I read the file and displayed total of each number in the function.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import os

enclosure_queue = Queue()
list=[]

def getAllFiles():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/test"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                file_path= os.path.join(root, file) 
                list.append(file_path)

def calc(i, q):
    while True:
        file = q.get()
        fileData = open(file, 'r')
        add=0
        for line in fileData:
            add= add + int(line)    
        print str(add) + '\n'
        q.task_done()

getAllFiles()
num_fetch_threads = len(list)
for i in range(num_fetch_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=calc, args=(i, enclosure_queue,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

for ind_file in list:
    enclosure_queue.put(ind_file)

enclosure_queue.join()
```

It displays the sum of data in lines of individual file, but I need to add up the results.
For example if the `calc` function's `add` has `300` , `200` and `500` , I want final result as `1000` . I thought of adding each result to a list and then splitting it in another function and adding them. Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Why do you have to do them in parallel? In any case, what comes to mind is using some sort of generator and yield `add` after finishing the task?

Comment: You can add each result into a list `x` and use `sum(x)`. No need to split in another function.

Comment: Also, try not to use `list` as a variable name. It'll mess stuff up since `list` is a keyword for, well, lists.

Comment: Because I have many files whose size is too big, to read it line by line I thought of doing it in parallel. Also, my main code performs various activities. Consider counting number of alphabets, number of vowels and so on.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim : yes, its just a demo kind of code, so I used the list variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `Queue` here. Use [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), and change your `calc` method accordingly. Also `threading.Thread` does not return results, whereas `multiprocessing.Pool.map` returns results.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def getAllFiles():
    my_files = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/test"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                file_path= os.path.join(root, file) 
                my_files.append(file_path)
    return my_files

def calc(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return sum(map(int, f.readlines()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_files = getAllFiles()
    num_fetch_threads = len(my_files)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_fetch_threads)
    results = pool.map(calc, my_files)
    result = sum(results)
    print result
```

Comment: I am getting Runtime exception:  Attempt to start a new process before the current process
 has finished its bootstrapping phase.

Comment: @imsirjayesh you need to put your code in `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition instead of directly putting it in your file. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Tahir , I will use this logic for my main use. Thanks a lot for the rescue operation. :)

Comment: I had one more question @Muhammad Tahir , If I need to return multiple values (it may be a list too), how do I need to handle the return statement.

Comment: @imsirjayesh you can return whatever you like, e.g. in your `calc` it can be `return my_sum, val2, val3, val4` or a list `return [my_sum, val2, val3, val4]`, whatever you return you will find it in your `results` list. In first example `results` will be a list of tuples and in second example it will be a list of lists.

Comment: Yes, I tried the same, if the function returns 3 lists, I need to add individual position's elements. So, sum function doesn't work here. I used [sum(x) for x in zip(results)] , but its giving unsupported operand type int and list.

Comment: Yeah! I was just writing my comment to put `*` before `results` :), Glad you resolved it.

Comment: You initiated the help :) Thanks to you. Will get back if I have something.

Comment: Consider the `calc()` calls another `display()` where a list is passed to the `display()`. These list consists `no_of_vowels` `no_of_alphabets` `no_of_odd_numbers`.
If `no_of_vowels` is passed, this `display()` function shows individual count of vowels `a: 7, e: 12, i: 15, o:5, u: 20`
If `no_of_odd_numbers` is passed, it displays individual count of odd numbers present like `1: 24 , 3: 15, 5: 52`
But the process pool needs return value from the `calc` function. I am facing issue while returning each dictionary from the `display()` to `calc()` for `n` files.How will I handle this situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106311/discussion-between-imsirjayesh-and-muhammad-tahir).